# Where Android Studio installs VULKAN_SDK?

Tags: android-studio, vulkan

I'm trying to cross-compile some code for Android in my Mac. This code requires Vulkan support, so I need a Vulkan SDK.

I already have Android Studio installed, so I initially assumed I had this SDK installed somewhere. But I can't find a value of `VULKAN_SDK` that works. I tried both
  `/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/`
and
  `/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/`,
but the first has only the `include` dir, and the second has additional structure inside the `lib` which, I believe, is breaking the CMake `FindVulkan` module.

On the specifics, if that helps: the code I'm trying to build is this one:https://github.com/Tencent/ncnn/wiki/how-to-build#build-for-android.

I also tried to download an SDK from https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home, but I'm redirected to https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/index.html, which is not helpful.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: The Android SDK/NDK include Vulkan headers and a link library, but they're not layed out the same way that LunarG's Vulkan SDK for other platforms is. Instead it follows the Android conventions. If you're using a Gradle build with the cmake integration, you should just be able to add vulkan to the list of platform libraries to link against, and headers should be found automatically, just like any other Android platform library -- no need for CMake's FindVulkan.

Comment: Thank you @JesseHall, that helps. The only issue is that I'm trying to compile this outside of Android Studio, on the command line, for which I still need to use CMake. So you're suggesting I could move this code to Android Studio, and build with Gradle? I'm not familiar with any of these tools, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Alternatively, do you know of any documentation describing the differences between LunarG's and Android's conventions, so I can create a Vulkan SDK file structure that would work with the existing `CMakeLists.txt` in https://github.com/Tencent/ncnn?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know conversion instructions. Are you trying to build the whole app (including building an apk, signing, etc.) with CMake? That's possible but you're going to be making several changes. For Vulkan, you really just need to figure out how to point it at the right include and library path, it shouldn't be much different than finding any other header/library in CMake.

Comment: I'm just trying to build a library (that's what ncnn is). Thank you for your help @JesseHall, I'll update here if I get this to work.